# Undo arrow has part of the neighboring image in it under IE11

Tags: bug, design, internet-explorer

Under rev 2014.11.19.2761, in IE11 v11.0.9600.17416, update 11.0.14 (KB3003057), a little bit of the image to the side appears in the undo image.

> [image: Undo Arrow with text to the side]
>   [image: Zoomed in undo arrow with circle]

This appears in the ask question dialog and the answer question dialog.

Comment: [status-norepro], Chromium 37.0.2062.120 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Safari 7.1 for Mac either.

Answer (score 3):

From Meta css:

```
.wmd-button>span {
  background-image: url("img/wmd-buttons.png?v=fd47b7eef34e");
  background-image: url("img/wmd-buttons.svg?v=7e1315195d13"),none;
  background-size: initial !important;
}
```

`initial` don't implemented in IE.

Also this can be a scale bug of IE for SVG sprite, because this equals to `background-position: -198px 0px;` for `#wmd-undo-button>span` which has style `background-position: -200px 0px;`.